# How to change CMS Page URL key in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I am developing my e-commerce website (www.fashionnow.in). I want to change my home page URL key in CMS Pages.
Here is current URL KEY Snap

[image]

I want to change this url key.
Please help me to solve this proplem

Comment: Why do you want to change it and what do you want it to be?

Answer (score 2):

You can change this `URL Key` in anything you'd like.

Because it is the home page we are talking about you will need to check a few additional things too.

1. Go to `System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page` and make sure that the page that you just edited is selected as the `Home Page` for your store.
2. Go to `Catalog > URL Rewrite Management` and set up a 301 Permant Redirect for this CMS page. This is necessary to prevent this page of being available under two different URLs (your stores `Base URL` and the `URL Key` that you have chosen) and avoid duplicate content.

> **Example:** If your home page `URL Key` is `home-page5` then set up the following URL Rewrite.
>
> ```
> Type: Custom
> ID Path: home-page5
> Request Path: home-page5
> Target Path: ../
> Redirect: (Permanent 301)
> Description: Redirect CMS home page to Base URL in order to prevent duplicate content
> ```